# Is sorting required for pagination?

Tags: solr

When we are implementing pagination in Solr using rows and start params, the results are returned depending on those.
I wanted to know if sorting is required in such a case. Suppose I have 30 records Is there a possibility that I specify start as 0 and rows as 5, then some results are returned and when I make a query again with start as 5 and rows as 5 then sorting order changes and some details are repeated?

Comment: Depends also on your use case. Will your users go through the whole result or just have a peek at the first few pages and are done ... If they use your app as you use google, I think you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the index has been optimized, merged or changed (for example by adding documents), the sequence of documents will not necessarily be maintained. This might also change the score of the documents.

In effect there should be no major cost if you include a sort for your uniqueKey, which is also required if you want to use cursorMarks later.